# DependencyResolver + Owin + WebApi2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, castle-windsor

One of the great advantages of Owin is that it has no dependency on `System.Web`. How on earth do I setup the DI if WebApi clearly requires something along those lines:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new ControllerInstaller());
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
config.DependencyResolver = ...
```

Where `config.DependencyResolver` requires a concrete of `IDependencyResolver` which comes from `System.Web.Http.Dependencies`?

I am especially interested in C# code which uses WebApi + Owin + Castle.Windsor (Google has not helped much yet).

Comment: Can you use the [IDependencyResolver in System.Web.Mvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)?

Comment: It works fine in webapi now. problem I am facing now is that when I run an integration test using the owin testserver I am getting "Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule" this is due to the introduced dependency on System.Web I suppose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to get it working using:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Bla.Startup))]
namespace Bla
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //...  
            var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new ControllerInstaller());
        var httpDependencyResolver = new WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(container);
            config.DependencyResolver = httpDependencyResolver;
            //...
        }
}

public class ControllerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
        .Pick().If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
        .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name))
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        //...
    }
}

internal class WindsorDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
    private readonly IDisposable _scope;

    public WindsorDependencyScope(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        _container = container;
        _scope = container.BeginScope();
    }

    public object GetService(Type t)
    {
        return _container.Kernel.HasComponent(t)
        ? _container.Resolve(t) : null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
    {
        return _container.ResolveAll(t)
        .Cast<object>().ToArray();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _scope.Dispose();
    }
}

internal sealed class WindsorHttpDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type t)
    {
        return _container.Kernel.HasComponent(t)
         ? _container.Resolve(t) : null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
    {
        return _container.ResolveAll(t)
        .Cast<object>().ToArray();
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new WindsorDependencyScope(_container);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the use of:

```
config.DependencyResolver = httpDependencyResolver;
```

introduces a dependency on system.web. So I have issues when I try to use the owin testserver in some integartion tests. I will post another question.

Comment: What are the issues? Are they just that you have another unwanted dll in the install directory or does it cause the program to malfunction?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look right here - ["Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API with Castle Windsor by Mark Seemann"](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/). Then at [Mark Seeman's blog archive](http://blog.ploeh.dk/archive/). He talks a lot about DI and WEB API and he uses Castle Windsor a lot. I bet Castle Windsor is his favorite DI container. When you look at the archive do not look just for WEB API. Sometimes he posts about WEB API under [different title](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/).

If you read [his excellent book](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) you will get very good understanding on the topic of IoC/DI. Very good book.

Comment: Thanks I read the blogs and book a while ago. Got it working in the end  (see answer below).

Comment: @csetzkorn you should mark your answer as the the correct one, not this one. This answer does not answer the question you asked at all. Your answer has a solution that works and you should mark it as the correct answer.